# Defining custom direct and inverse limits

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I would like to define custom [direct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) (a/k/a inductive) and [inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit) (a/k/a projective) limits, as used in category theory, for example. (Not the limit as used in calculus.) In other words, I'm looking for a custom version of `\lim_\to`.

Rather than using `\varinjlim` and `\varprojlim`, I want

1. a tikz arrow instead of the usual arrow
2. either

   - a variable arrow length, depending on whether the limit is used in textstyle or displaystyle, or
   - a way of not adding any extra space to the lines, so that the lines have even spacing.
3. both a regular and a bold version of the limits.

So far

```
\newcommand{\Dlim}{%
  \mathop{\mathbf{lim}}\limits_{%
    \tikz[baseline=-1ex]
      \draw[-stealth,line width=.4pt] (0ex,0ex) -- (3ex,0ex);
  }
}
```

is looking pretty reasonable, except for the fact that it adds extra space to the lines.

I tried adjusting the `baseline`, but that seems only to add space for both negative and positive values, either between the arrow and the operator, or between the whole limit and the next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you just change the `\to` arrow and use `tikz` to draw that:

[image]

---

As per your comments you want an *arrow without limits* but a longer arrow when in `\displaystye`.  That can be achieved with the use of `\mathchoice`:

[image]

although I am not sure exactly what this symbol means.

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\MyTo}{\mathbin{\tikz[baseline] \draw[-stealth,line width=.4pt] (0ex,0.4ex) -- (2ex,0.4ex);}}

\begin{document}
In inline mode we can use \verb|\to| to obtain $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ 
or using \verb|\MyTo| we obtain $\lim_{x \MyTo 0} g(x)$.  
This should have no affect on the interline spacing as you can see in this paragraph.
And it should also work in display mode:
\[
\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)
\lim_{x \MyTo 0} g(x)
\]
\end{document}
```

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\MyTo}[1]{\mathbin{\,\tikz[baseline] \draw[-stealth,line width=.4pt] (0ex,0.4ex) -- (#1,0.4ex);}}
\newcommand{\Dlim}{%
    \mathchoice
      {\lim_{\MyTo{3.0ex}}}% \displaystyle
      {\lim_{\MyTo{2.5ex}}}% \textstyle
      {\lim_{\MyTo{2.0ex}}}% \scriptstyle
      {\lim_{\MyTo{2.0ex}}}% \scriptscriptstyle
}

\begin{document}
In inline mode we can use 
using \verb|\Dlim| to obtain $\Dlim g(x)$.  
This should have no affect on the interline spacing as you can see in this paragraph.
And in display mode the arrow is slightly longer:
\[
\Dlim g(x)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am only using the arrow without limits, which means that in displaystyle the arrow from your code looks too short. If I make it longer, in textstyle it will look too long. One solution would be to force displaystyle for both, but then extra space is added (to lineskip?), which is not needed and doesn't look good.

Comment: @Earthliŋ: So you want _just_ the arrow, and to have the arrow length be longer in `displaystyle`.

Comment: Right, just the arrow and either not adding extra space and always below, or smaller when on the side.

Comment: @Earthliŋ: Please see alternate solution. Also, can you edit your question to show where this symbol is used in the literature as I don't have enough math knowledge to be familiar with a _limit_ that does not have limits.

Comment: Using `\mathchoice` works like a charm, thank you! I edited in references from Wikipedia about the limits without limits ;).

Comment: @Earthliŋ: Thanks for the links about _unlimited_ limits. :-) Always fun to learn new math concepts -- well, at least for me.