# How to renew the \rightarrow command?

Tags: macros

I am playing and exploring the *renewcommand* and *newcommand* right now, and I tried to do:

```
\renewcommand{\rightarrow}{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\rightarrow}}}
```

I get it to work with the *newcommand* like this:

```
\newcommand{\largerightarrow}{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\rightarrow}}}
```

However, the newcommand would require longer name, and it would be nicer in this case to use the standard command *rightarrow*.

I've noticed that I haven't used the original size of the $\rightarrow$ once yet, therefor I'd like to have that renewcommand in my template for my math documents.

Comment: `\let\RightArrow\rightarrow\renewcommand\rightarrow{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\RightArrow}}`?

Comment: Related Question: In case you need further customization of the arrow, in [Defining custom direct and inverse limits](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206859/defining-custom-direct-and-inverse-limits/206871#206871) I define a `\MyTo` arrows which uses `tikz` to draw it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renewing a command with the command itself in its definition won't work because `TeX` doesn't remember what the command was previously as you're redefining it.

The code you're looking for is something along the lines of:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{relsize}

\let\RightArrow\rightarrow
\renewcommand\rightarrow{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\RightArrow}}}

\begin{document}
    4 colours + 13card/colour $\rightarrow$ 52 cards
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get _Undefined Control Sequence_ when I do that command.

Comment: It was missing a brace. Fixed that now!

Comment: @1010011010: Can you post a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and appropriate packages.